# Ensuring unique index on a sharded Mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, indexing, sharding

I have sharded my mongo collection with the ObjectId field '_id' as the shard key.
My need is to ensure an unique index on this collection.

Unfortunately, you can't create unique indexes on a sharded Collection.

MongoDB suggests :

> Use a secondary collection to enforce uniqueness.
>   [docs](http://www.dba86.com/docs/mongo/2.6/tutorial/enforce-unique-keys-for-sharded-collections.html)

But there can always be consistency issues defeating this method as mongoDB doesn't support transactions.

For example,

- We have collections *Sample* and *Sample_proxy* (Index collection). *Sample* is sharded while *Sample_proxy* is not. So an unique index can be created on *Sample_proxy*.
- Before inserting into *Sample*, always first try to insert into *Sample_proxy*.
- If insert into *Sample_proxy* fails => unique index violation.
- If not, do the actual insert into *Sample*. 
  Note: If actual insert fails, remember to delete the document from *Sample_proxy* to ensure consistency.

Sounds foolproof, But!

What if you successfully insert into *Sample_proxy* and before the actual insert, the machine goes down.
Peeking into two different collections cannot be done atomically.
I don't see any way where inconsistency can be completely eliminated.

If there's a solution for this, please enlighten me.

Comment: Wouldn't MongoDB's use of [journaling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/journaling/) address this case?

Comment: I hope there is a better way of addressing this case

Comment: My point is that journaling prevents the potential inconsistency you're concerned about from happening. That said, you could also use your unique columns as your shard key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Peeking into two different collections cannot be done atomically

Turns out it can be done. I used distributed locks to prevent the potential inconsistency mentioned in the question, using Apache Zookeeper (Curator Framework to be specific)

Note:
Employing distributed locks could easily bottleneck the throughput of any distributed system. **The key is to only lock when absolutely necessary**.